# Are there any SMTP servers written in PHP or Go?

Tags: php, email, smtp, go

I don't mean [SMTP/IMAP clients](http://roundcube.net/), I mean a working [SMTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMTP) server that can both receive and send email.

There are lots of examples of partial [PHP](https://github.com/flashmob/Guerrilla-SMTPd) and [Go](http://websomtep.danga.com/) SMTP servers that only listen for SMTP connections - aren't there any which show how to send mail?

I'm really interested in learning this second half of the Simple Mail Transfer Protocol. I understand that there are a lot of bad servers which vary from the standard - but I want to learn how the whole protocol from start to finish is implemented.

Comment: Which parts would be missing compared to a MUA sending via SMTP?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, as long as that MUA is also listening for email (which makes it a server). I'm just still fuzzy on how a sending via SMTP works and I'm looking for an example implementation in PHP or Go. Almost everything I've seen is a user agent connecting via SMTP to a SMTP server (like gmail) which then does _________ to send the email to the actual destination.

Comment: Are you sure you need to create your own server?  Why not use a GNU server and then write your own front end using `php IMAP` routines?

Comment: @JefforyJ.Beckers, I've been using Postfix to handle my email needs thus far. I even wrote a tiny [PHP SMTP client](https://gist.github.com/2002233). However, I want to learn more about the process.

Comment: PHP isn't really designed for protocols besides HTTP. Is there even a way to make PHP listen on a raw socket?

Comment: if it is simply a learning excercise, read through the original RFCs (RFC 821 I believe) which would certainly illustrate all the componants and transactions that you would have to code for.

Comment: @Dave well [RFC 5321](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5321) would be more relevant as its the current RFC and includes things like ESMTP.

Comment: @Brendan Long PHP does have socket functions. I've previously answered  a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11968363/imap-or-pop3-server-implemented-in-php/11973533#11973533. Of course, the implementation was pretty such a joke, since it's far too fragile for actual use. An SMTP in PHP would be even more pointless. In an environment where you can't run a real server, you probably can't get mails routed to you either.

Comment: @Burhan you are correct, thus my qualifier of `original`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think you misunderstand how SMTP is supposed to work. Here is a simplified version:

1. The Mail User Agent (MUA) queues a message for delivery by sending it to the Mail Submission Agent (MSA).
2. MSA connects to the Mail Transfer Agent (the "smtp server") over SMTP.
3. The MTA then uses DNS to lookup the MX record for the recipient's domain. It then contacts the recipient's MX server as a *SMTP client*.
4. The MX server accepts the envelope; it then forwards it to a Mail Delivery Agent (MDA).
5. MDA then puts the envelope in some message store where some IMAP or POP3 server reads messages. The MUA then connects to these servers to retrieve the message.

The entire process uses three main commands. `MAIL`, `RCPT` and `DATA`.

- `MAIL` = Envelope information, bounce addresses, etc.
- `RCTP` = The recipient.
- `DATA` = The payload.

The SMTP server responds - much like HTTP actually, with error codes and based on that, the MTA knows what to do with the envelope (its a bounce back, so send appropriate reply, etc.)

In this process there is no such thing as "retrieve email" (ignoring [`ETRN`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1985) for a bit); as SMTP is purely for email transmission and not retrieval.

Comment: So, rather than a MUA (like outlook) connecting to a MSA or MTA (like smtp.gmail.com), it could actually do the MX lookup itself and connect to the receiving MX server (example.com) and send the SMTP payload for `bob@example.com`?

Comment: Yes, of course - but typically there is a separate process (it doesn't need to be a _program_ in the traditional sense) that is dedicated for network communication. This is what is referred to as "MSA". For example, `sendmail` is a MSA. You tell it "hey deliver this", and it takes care of the rest.

Comment: Also, bear in mind that most ISPs now block outbound port 25. So to send mail you have to either (A) use the ISP's SMTP server as a relay or (B) connect on an alternate port (e.g. 587 or 465). Most servers will only accept mail from authenticated users on 587, and you can't depend on all servers supporting SSL (465). And finally, the mail doesn't always go through first try. The MTA worries about retries and will re-attempt even when your computer is off.

Answer (score 3):

I found a full [SMTP server](https://github.com/jasonjohnson/php-smtp) written in PHP - even includes a nasty open relay.

```
$ sudo php php-smtp.php [ip-address] [port]
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no "second half" of SMTP, just the protocol.  If your MUA interacts directly over TCP with the mail server (rather than using a helper program like the **/usr/bin/sendmail** binary found on most Unixes), then it uses the SMTP protocol.  The MTA uses the same protocol to talk to other MTAs when delivering the mail.  It may use a larger set of the available verbs, depending on the circumstances.

Seeing the code of a PHP or Go implementation of an MTA would show you how one person/team has *implemented* the SMTP protocol.

Answer (score 1):

THere's a PHP smtpd server that just processes mail -  https://github.com/flashmob/Guerrilla-SMTPd 
and a port to go
https://github.com/flashmob/go-guerrilla

Answer (score 1):

There is a non blocking SMTP server writen in PHP on top of ReactPhp:

https://bitbucket.org/david_garcia_garcia/smtpserver

It is designed for the end user to have custom Authentication and Delivery implementations, the rest of the SMTP behaviour works out of the box.