# Programmatically inserting messages to an email account with CPanel API

Tags: php, email, cpanel, pop3

I'm looking for a way to programmatically insert messages into a specific email account - created and maintained with CPanel.

I have a website that provides a webmail interface for a video game's inner messsaging (using its API) and I would like to take this service one step further and make the messages available on a POP3 server.

I have looked for a solution multiple ways so far:

---

**Insert mails using CPanel's API:** I could not find an api call for this, only for creating new accounts (with https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/SDK/UAPI+Functions+-+Email%3A%3Aadd_pop) This is the preferred method for me as I'd rather leave alone the filesystem.

---

**Manually insert the mails to the filesystem:** I found out, that Cpanel stores email data in *root/mail/domain/user/* but I have no knowledge of the exact file structure. I recognize the maildirsize file and the other directories containing the mails, but I have no knowledge of the maildirsize file's structure (seems to contain 2 integers divided by a space per line) and also the mail file's filenames are as well not obvious. This is an example of a filename:

```
1422094110.H186037P182351.hosting-server-domain.com,S=15645
```

I'd rather use this method as a backup method, because there is very little (or I didn't find any useful) documentation available.

---

**Simply E-mail all messages with custom headers:** This would be far the easiest method, however the hosting provider has a very strict anti-spam policy and the outgoing message number is limited.

---

**Implement an own POP3 server:** I played around with @cleong 's PHP implementation (https://stackoverflow.com/a/11973533/1030464) and while it worked on localhost, I am not sure it'd be a joyride on the live page. I found a Perl implementation as well which might be worth a try, but I have never ever worked with Perl and I'd rather look at another solution before learning how to implement and integrate that module.

Thank you for reading all this,

Bálint

Comment: You will have to learn about either ***exim, postfix or sendmail*** depending on what that given cPanel installation is ***using as MTA***, there you will find all the information on the mail storage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like the email is being stored using the Maildir format. This makes inserting mails fairly straightforward. For full details see the [Maildir specification](http://cr.yp.to/proto/maildir.html), but in summary:

- The hardest part: create a guaranteed-unique name for the mail, using the techniques suggested on that page (e.g. local hostname plus high-resolution timestamp plus high-quality random number).
- Create a file with this name under `.../Maildir/tmp/`
- Rename the file to be under `.../Maildir/new`. This renaming step ensures that only fully-formed mails are seen by the mail software - i.e. no other process will attempt to look at the file when you're half way through writing it.

That's it!

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for! (I'll award the bounty in 12 hours, the system asked me to wait)
Edit: Luckily all the mails come with a unique ID so I'll just use that. :)

Comment: Implemented, working well! Thank you again, rep is transferred

Comment: Seriously, this is a major nerdgasm